# What is the name of the topic/field that covers graphing $\frac{1}{f(x)}$, $|f(x)|$, and $f(|x|)$, given the graph of $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, graphing-functions

> Given the function $f(x)$ and its graph I am asked to graph the functions $\frac{1}{f(x)},$ $|f(x)|$ and $f(|x|)$.

---

What is the name of this topic?

I know it is some sort of transformation, yet I can't seem to find any resources online for it.

Comment: You are looking for 'function transformations': [this link](https://www.shelovesmath.com/algebra/advanced-algebra/absolute-value-transformations/) about function transformations with absolute values may help.

Comment: The topic is "analytic geometry".